# Why 'reject' filter is not working in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to run the following code in ansible

```
-debug:
   msg: {{ timediff| reject('search','2') | list }}
```

here timediff is a list return by jinja2.

But ansible showing

```
template error while templating string: no filter named 'reject'. String: {{ timediff | reject('search', '2') | list }}
```

this error .

My setting:

```
ansible = 2.5.5
jinja2 = 2.6
python=2.7.13
```

how to solve this error .Please help .

Comment: how to do opposite of this to accept or allow only

Answer (score 0):

You are using outdated Jinja2, particularly if you look at [the documentation for the `reject` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#reject) you'll see:

> *New in version 2.7.*

Upgrade.